# Optimal Screen Resolution to capture screen cast for a demo

Tags: resolution, demo

I am making a screen cast nor capture of the functionality of our application.I am doing it on my laptop,I am supposed to connect a projector or a tv to show the demo.What would be the optimal screen resolution? Or is there something like that? What is the resolution you choose.Sometime the projector or tv doesnt support some resolutions so the demo.exe you make at high resolution ends up clipped or too big so you are screwed? I am using adobe captivate to make the exe of the demo screen cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use the smallest non-widescreen resolution I can and still show what I need to show.

Most of the time this is either 800x600 or 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of TV you have to be able to display. NTCS (US) has 720 by 480, PAL (Europe) 768 by 576. In computers I found a still astonishing number of 800 by 600 SVGA beamers.

If I were you I would record multiple sets, maybe NTCS, SVGA, and Full HD at 1920 by 1080.

To look at all resolutions look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution).